# Correct word generation without repetitions

Tags: python

How many five-letter words can you make from a 26-letter alphabet (no repetitions)?
I am writing a program that generates names (just words) from 5 letters in the format: consonant_vowel_consistent_vowel_consonant. Only 5 letters. in Latin. I just want to understand how many times I have to run the cycle for generation. At 65780, for example, repetitions already begin. Can you please tell me how to do it correctly?

```
import random
import xlsxwriter

consonants = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q',
              'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']

vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('GeneratedNames.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


def names_generator(size=5, chars=consonants + vowels):
    for y in range(65780):
        toggle = True
        _id = ""
        for i in range(size):
            if toggle:
                toggle = False
                _id += random.choice(consonants)
            else:
                toggle = True
                _id += random.choice(vowels)
        worksheet.write(y, 0, _id)
        print(_id)
    workbook.close()


names_generator()
```

Comment: Do you just need to generate all the unique C_V_C_V_C words without repetitions?

Comment: "no repetitions" meaning a letter can only appear once in a word?

Comment: If you want to ensure no repetitions, why are you using `random` at all?

Comment: @AbhimanyuShekhawat, no, I need as many "_id" without repetition as possible

Comment: @superbrain I think that's just a misspelling of "consonant".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicates, you shouldn't use randomness but simply generate all such IDs:

```
from itertools import product

C = consonants
V = vowels
for id_ in map(''.join, product(C, V, C, V, C)):
    print(id_)
```

or

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, product

for id_ in map(''.join, product(*islice(cycle((consonants, vowels)), 5))):
    print(id_)
```

Comment: This allows duplicates, he wanted no repeats.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Not true, no IDs get repeated here.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Yeah, it's not perfectly clear. In the comments under the question they were even asked "Do you need X?" and they answered with "No, I need X". Confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get 3 different consonants and 2 different vowels and get the `permutations` of those to generate all possible "names".

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

names = [a+b+c+d+e for cons in combinations(consonants, 3)
                   for a, c, e in permutations(cons)
                   for vow in combinations(vowels, 2)
                   for b, d in permutations(vow)]
```

There are only 205,200 = 20x19x18x6x5 in total, so this will take no time at all for 5 letters, but will quickly take longer for more. That is, if by "no repetitions" you mean that no letter should occur more than once. If, instead, you just want that no consecutive letters are repeated (which is already guaranteed by alternating consonants and vowels), or that no names are repeated (which is guaranteed by constructing them without randomness), you can just use `itertools.product` instead, for a total of 288,000 = 20x20x20x6x6 names:

```
names = [a+b+c+d+e for a, c, e in product(consonants, repeat=3)
                   for b, d in product(vowels, repeat=2)]
```

If you want to generate them in random order, you could just `random.shuffle` the list afterwards, or if you want just a few such names, you can use `random.sample` or `random.choice` on the resulting list.

Comment: Hmm, bit confusing to shadow `c` like that. And I don't think you need `combinations`, could just use `permutations`'s second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

itertools allows for non repetitive permutations  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

```
import itertools, re
names = list(itertools.product(consonants + vowels, repeat=5))

consonants_regex = "(" + "|".join(consonants) + ")"
vowels_regex = "(" + "|".join(vowels) + ")"
search_string = consonants_regex + vowels_regex + consonants_regex + vowels_regex + consonants_regex
names_format = ["".join(name) for name in names if re.match(search_string, "".join(name))]
```

Output:

```
>>> len(names)
11881376
>>> len(names_format)
288000
```

Comment: Hm, why do I get a different count than you? Ah, you allow for repeated letters...

Comment: Combinations doesn't allow for things such as BABAB. So depends if the question allows  things like this or whether each letter in a "name" needs to be unique as well

Answer (score 1):

I want to make sure to answer your question

> I just want to understand how many times I have to run the cycle for
> generation

since I think it is important to get a better intuition about the problem.

You have 20 consonants and 6 vowels and in total that yields 20x6x20x6x20 = 288000 different combinations for words. Since it is sequential, you can split it up to make that easier to understand. You have 20 different consonants you can put as the 1st letter and for each one 6 vowels you can attach afterwards = 20x6 = 120. Then you can keep going and say for those 120 combinations you can add 20 consonants for each = 120x20 = 2400 ... and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, I understood everything! Very useful!